# How to change a input type hidden value of a selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, thymeleaf

I have 5 radio buttons in one form and 5 input type hidden values corresponding to each radio button. By default, the value of radio buttons and hidden values are 0. Now, I want to change the selected radio button value and its corresponding hidden value to 1. Also, if I re-change the selected radio button then it should make the old selected radio button value and corresponding hidden value to 0 and make the newly selected radio button value and its corresponding button value to 1. I'm able to change the value of selected to radio button and its corresponding hidden value to 1, but if I re-select to another radio button it's not changing the old hidden value to 0 and new hidden value to 1.

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=correctanswer]').on('change', function() {

            if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
                $(this).val('1');
            //  $('#correct').val($(this).val());       
            }
             $('input:radio').each(function() {
                  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                      $(this).val('1');
                //   $('#correct').val($(this).val());
                      } 
                  else {
                      $(this).val('0');
                    //  $('#correct').val($(this).val());
                  }
                }); 
             $('input:hidden').each(function() {
                  if($('input[type=radio][name=correctanswer]').is(':checked')) {
                    //  $(this).val('1');
                      $('#correct').val('1');
                      } 
                  else {
                      $(this).val('0');
                      $('#correct').val('0');
                  }
                  
                }); 
        });
```

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveQuestionAnswer}" th:object="${question}" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="question" class="control-label">Question</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="question" cols="40" rows="5" th:name="question" placeholder="question" class="form-control"></textarea>


  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="30" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 3" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 4" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 5" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your radio buttons using `each` loop then use `.closest()` to get the closest div to that radio and if that radio is `checked` assign value to input-box either`1` or `0`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=correctanswer]').on('change', function() {
//loop through each radio
  $('input:radio').each(function() {
  //if checked
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //get closest div with class=form-group and add value to input
      $(this).closest(".form-group").find("input[name=correct]").val('1');

    } else {
    //add 0
      $(this).closest(".form-group").find("input[name=correct]").val('0');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveQuestionAnswer}" th:object="${question}" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="question" class="control-label">Question</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="question" cols="40" rows="5" th:name="question" placeholder="question" class="form-control"></textarea>


  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="text" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="30" class="form-control" name="options" width="50"
      value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="text" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="text" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 3" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="text" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 4" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control-input" width="5" type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="correctanswer" th:name="correctanswer" value="0" /><input type="text" name="correct" id="correct" value="0"><input type="text" size="40" class="form-control" name="options"
      width="50" value="" th:name="options" placeholder="Option 5" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```